# Current Location issue in react-native-google-places-autocomplete

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-google-places-autocomplete to get places suggestions based on user's current location. And it is working fine but the only issue I am facing is that whenever the 'Current Location' button is clicked, it sets the input field with value 'Current Location' and then shows the location results in the form of the list below it.

I don't want it to set `currentLocationLabel` value in the input field.

[image]

Here's my Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation');

const LocationAutocompleteScreen = props => {
    return (
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder='Search Location...'
          minLength={3}
          autoFocus={true}
          returnKeyType={'search'}
          listViewDisplayed='auto'
          fetchDetails={true}

          onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            const locParam = {
                description: data.description,
                placeId: data.place_id,
                location: details.geometry.location
            }
            props.navigation.navigate('LocationSearch', {locParam} )
          }}

          getDefaultValue={() => {
            return '' // text input default value
          }}

          query={{
            key: 'API_KEY',
            language: 'en',
            components: 'country:in',
          }}

          styles={{
            textInputContainer: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
              borderTopWidth: 0,
              borderBottomWidth: 0,
              marginTop: 16,
              marginHorizontal: 16
            },
            textInput: {
              marginLeft: 0,
              marginRight: 0,
              padding: 8,
              minHeight: 30,
              color: '#000000',
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            predefinedPlacesDescription: {
              color: '#1faadb',
            },
            listView: {
                paddingHorizontal: 8
            },
            description: {
                fontWeight: '700',
                letterSpacing: 0.5,
                color: '#5d5d5d'
            }
        }}

        currentLocation={true}
        currentLocationLabel='Current Location'
        
        
        nearbyPlacesAPI='GoogleReverseGeocoding' // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
        
        //renderDescription={row => row.description || row.formatted_address || row.name}
        // GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{
        //   // available options for GoogleReverseGeocoding API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro
        // }}
        // GooglePlacesSearchQuery={{
        //   // available options for GooglePlacesSearch API : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search
        //   rankby: 'distance',
        //   types: 'food'
        // }}

        //filterReverseGeocodingByTypes={['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3']} // filter the reverse geocoding results by types - ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_3'] if you want to display only cities

        />
    );
}

export default LocationAutocompleteScreen;
```

Comment: The package does not allow for anything other than the currentLocationLabel be show. What do you want to show instead? If it something consistent, you can probably patch-package it.

Comment: @StevenBell It is showing the currentLocationLabel...but when currentLocationLabel is clicked then whatever string value I assigned to currentLocationLabel gets set as input field value.. I want the input field to be empty when currentLocationLabel is clicked...in the image (in the asked question) you can see I clicked "Current Location" and it was set as the value in the input field.

Comment: I understand. You can use patch-package, it should only be a one-line change.